# Multiple names for the same struct in c

Tags: c, inheritance, struct, typedef

Is it possible to create multiple names for the same struct in C?
The idea is that data structures in a communication protocol which has the same layout but different names, could share the same definition.

Example:

```
struct flags_type1 {
        uint8_t flag1;
        uint8_t flag2;
};

struct flags_type2 {
            uint8_t flag1;
            uint8_t flag2;
};
/* The flag layout for type 2 is identical to type 1, so somehow
 * just reuse the struct for type 1, but with a new name.
 * (For readability in the implementation. */

/* *** HERE: Insert solution code here. Something with typedef? *** */

struct flags_type3 {
        uint8_t flag1;
        uint8_t flag2;
        uint8_t flag3;
};

struct msg_object {
        uint8_t type_id_code;
        union {
                struct flags_type1 type1;
                struct flags_type2 type2;
                struct flags_type3 type3;
         } flags;
         uint8_t payload[7];
};


/* Utilization: */
struct msg_object *msg;
switch (msg->type_id_code) {
case TYPE1:
        do_things_type1(msg->flags.type1);
        break;
case TYPE2:
        do_things_type2(msg->flags.type2);
        break;
case TYPE3:
        do_things_type3(msg->flags.type3);
        break;
}
```

Motivation:
I am implementing a communication protocol which can transmit message objects which has different types (Specifically, SDOs in CANopen). Each object has a 5-bit field of status flags, and some of the objects has an identical layout of this field. There is also a 3-bit field which identifies the object type. These two fields, are fitted into a single byte.

The idea is thus to utilize the correct flag layout based on the type identifier. To make this choice of flag layout intuitive, it seems sensible to make all the type names present, without defining the same layout twice.

I suppose this, technically, is a inheritance question.

//audun

Comment: And what is the question ? BTW : `switch (msg->type_id_code & 7) {` or *depending on the order of your bit fields*: `switch (msg->type_id_code >> 5 ) {` And do note that your `uint8_t payload[7];` will always be presumed to be at the same offset, independent of msgtype.

Comment: So, struct flags_type1 and struct flags_type2 are the same, so I would like to be able to do something like 
typedef struct flags_type1 struct flags_type2; <-- does not compile

Comment: Instead of defining new `struct flags_type2` you can create an alias to `flags_type1` named `flags_type2`: `typedef struct flags_type1 flags_type2;`.

Comment: vonaka: Ah, I think that's what I am looking for, I just could not figure out where to leave in and leave out the struct keyword.

Comment: @vonaka You got your typedef backwards there.

Comment: @ThomasJager yep, edited, but anyway there is an answer already.

Comment: @AudunKnudsroed  [IMHO]  try to avoid typedefs until you really need them. In most cases you only need the struct definitions. Having too many names for the same thing is only confusing.

Comment: The drawback of the typedef solution is that it obfuscates the struct keyword, so that I get 
union {
struct flags_type1;
flags_type2;
struct flags_type3;
} flags;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two tagged types (tagged types are structs, unions, or enums) with different tags (what comes after the struct/union/enum keyword)
point to the same type (you can think of `struct x` like a compile-time pointer pointing to the type definition). In other words, `struct x` can never alias `struct y`. But you can have different `typedefs` pointing to the same type.

```
typedef struct flags_type1 {
        uint8_t flag1;
        uint8_t flag2;
} flags_type1; //flags_type1 is now both a tag and a global typename
typedef flags_type1 flags_type2; //flags_type2 == flags_type1
```

You might want `flags_type1` and `flags_type2` to have different types, though (for the sake of the functions), in which case in pure C you can do:

```
struct flags2 { struct flags1 embedded; }
```

With this you'll then have to mention the member name (embedded) to access the members. This is unavoidable in straight C (if you don't want to use a macro for the member set), though on gcc/clang with `-fms-extensions` you can do:

```
struct flags2 { struct flags1; }
//w/ -fms-extensions, reuseses the body and
//makes struct flags2 implicitly convertible to struct flags1
```

and then access the members directly.

Apart from this, there's always macros.

Comment: "IOW, struct x can never alias struct y"
Thanks, aliasing struct x as struct y was exactly what I wanted to do, so this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what your trying to achieve. If I'm not misunderstanding this, I guess it can be done with `typedef`. Like:

```
struct flags_type {
        uint8_t flag1;
        uint8_t flag2;
};

typedef struct flags_type type1;
typedef struct flags_type type2;
```

Comment: You could also write an example of usage like `type1 f1; f1.flag1 = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need typedefs, and you can nest structure definitions:

---

```
struct msg_object {
        uint8_t type_id_code;
        union {
                struct t01 {
                        uint8_t flag1;
                        } type1;
                struct t02 {
                        uint8_t flag1;
                        uint8_t flag2;
                        } type2;
                struct t03 {
                        uint8_t flag1;
                        uint8_t flag2;
                        uint8_t flag3;
                        } type3;
                } flags;
         uint8_t payload[7];
        };
```

---

The code for the handler:

---

```
switch (msg->type_id_code) { // may need to mask here ...
case TYPE1:
        do_things_type1(msg->flags.type1); // <<-- passed BY VALUE
        break;
        ...
```

---

```
The called function could be:
```

---

```
void do_things_type1(struct t1 this) {
        printf("%x", this.flag1 & 0xff);
        ...
}
```